# Where can I add code on grails server angular client

Tags: angular, rest, email, grails, groovy

I followed [this guide](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a10b5f580aca75eadc12d6c/grails-3-angular-5-profile-crud-web-application-example) and modified the angular side. I have only worked with grails before and now I have a problem. How can I add a function to the post method? Or where and how in the server side can I add an automatically send email funtion when register a new customer?

From what I had worked before with only grails this was made with the controller and modifying the `save()` method, but now I cannot find where this method is or the customer controller.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me. Also, I do not understand how the request works with angular.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add a function to the post method?

The `post` method *is* a function.  In general they are referred to as methods in Groovy, but in this context those names mean the same thing.  The language doesn't allow you to add a method to a method (or a function to a function, or any combo of those).

> Or where and how in the server side can I add an automatically send
> email funtion when register a new customer?

That depends on a number of factors in your app but assuming your app is using GORM, you could have an asynchronous listener respond to `PreInsertEvent` (or similar) and in the listener initiate the sending of an email.  If you are not using GORM, you could put the mail sending code in a Grails Service and call that service method from your controller action that supports registering a new customer.